# Prove that $I=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} I_{\alpha}$ is a proper ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Let $R$ be a unital ring and let $X=\{I_{\alpha} : \alpha \in A\}$ be a totally ordered (by subset) set of proper ideals of $R,$ indexed by some set $A.$ Prove that $I=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} I_{\alpha}$ is a proper ideal of $R.$

By the definition of a proper ideal, I need to show that there is some element in $R$ that is not in $I$ and that $I$ is an ideal of $R.$ But I'm not sure how to arrive at this answer using just the information given in the question.

Edit: my previous answer was complete gibberish. I tried to use Zorn's lemma because the question looked similar to one that I solved using the lemma, but it turns out that that approach is completely flawed, as pointed as in the comments and the answer.

Comment: Why do you introduce the $a_i$s? The exercise doesn't mention any set of generators for the ideal. All you have to is that thz union of the ideals is stable by addition and scalar multiplication, and that it doesn't contain $1$.

Comment: If you're having trouble seeing what's going on, you can take your proof and apply it to an example. Like $\Bbb Z[x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots]$, with $I_n=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see at all how any of the things you wrote proves that $I$ is a proper ideal. Here is how you usually prove such things:

We first show that $I$ is a proper subset of $R$.

Assume to the contrary that $R=\bigcup_a I_a$. In particular, there is $a\in A$ such that $1\in I_a$. But then $I_a= R$, contradicting that $I_a$ is a proper ideal of $R$.

Next, we prove that $I$ is an ideal of $R$.

Clearly $I\neq \emptyset$. Let $x,y\in I, r\in R$. Then $x\in I_a$ for some $a\in A$ and $y\in I_b$ for some $b\in A$. Because $I_b$ is an ideal, $ry\in I_b$. Because our collection of ideals is totally ordered, we either have $I_a\subseteq I_b$ or $I_b\subseteq I_a$. Assume wlog the former, i.e. $I_a\subseteq I_b$. Then also $x\in I_b$ and because $I_b$ is an additive subgroup $x+ry\in I_b\subseteq I$.

This proves that $I$ is an ideal.

Comment: isn't I not empty because it contains $0$? also, why do we need the condition that $x+ry\in I_b$? why can't we just say that $x-y\in I_b$? isn't that enough to satisfy the ideal test?

Comment: Yes $I$ is non empty because it contains $0$. Checking that $x-y\in I$ is not enough to conclude you have an ideal. This just shows that we have an additive subgroup, but we also need that left/right multiplication of ring elements with elements of $I$ stays in $I$.

Comment: If you have that, it is indeed sufficient that $x-y \in I$ for all $x,y \in I$. Note that it even is sufficient to show that $x+y \in I$ for all $x,y \in I$ (because your ring is unital, and you can then pick $r=-1$ to obtain that additive inverses are in $I$).